# ColdFusion 2021 - how to browse pages in a browser

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have installed ColdFusion 2021 and can access the administrator at the following URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

I have created a site and set up the datasource, but I can't preview it in a browser.  I keep getting a 404 error — The page you are trying to access can not be displayed. Please try again or notify the administrator.  When I look at my DSN settings, it's default to port 1433, not 8500.  When I click 'verify' for the datasource, nothing happens.  The status is blank.  What am I overlooking?

This is the URL I'm using to test (folder name/file name):  http://localhost:8500/mysite/addAgent.cfm

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The port 8500 for the Coldfusion administrator has it's own webserver built in.

The CF admin will only serve it's own pages.  You usually need a separate webserver that talks to Coldfusion with a handler.  IIS, Apache, etc.   Try removing the port for your own custom pages.  Think of it as a separate site.

Comment: So, what URL would I use to browse then?  In the past, on another computer, I used http://localhost:8500/ plus the folder name and then the file, and it worked great.  I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing at least 3 concepts.

1. You can get to the CF admin. That is a good thing.
2. Inside the CF admin is the DSN Settings. That is just a normal CF admin page. Port 1433 is how SQL Server communicates with systems external to it, like ColdFusion. Port 1433 is not a page.
3. ColdFusion has a built in server. Are you looking for the directory that ColdFusion uses for its built in server, `cf_root/cfusion/wwwroot` You can just add a subdirectory and file as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Will.  I'm not able to browse any of the CF files on localhost.  Whether I use http://localhost:8500/ or http://127.0.0.1:8500 I get an error message.  Yes, this is what I'm doing:  "ColdFusion has a built in server. Are you looking for the directory that ColdFusion uses for its built in server, cf_root/cfusion/wwwroot You can just add a subdirectory and file as needed."